# Taking in a Triangle as an input in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a triangle which takes in user inputted values and from the values would like to find the maximum route in these inputs. I intitally asked the question to find the maximum route in this: [Finding the Maximum Route in a given input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053540/finding-the-maximum-route-in-a-given-input)

Code:

```
def triangle(rows):
    for rownum in range (rows):
        PrintingList = list()
        print ("Row no. %i" % rownum)
        for iteration in range (rownum):
            newValue = input("Please enter the %d number:" %iteration)
            PrintingList.append(int(newValue))
            print()
def routes(rows,current_row=0,start=0):
    for i,num in enumerate(rows[current_row]):
        #gets the index and number of each number in the row
        if abs(i-start) > 1:   # Checks if it is within 1 number radius, if not it skips this one. Use if not (0 <= (i-start) < 2) to check in pyramid
            continue
        if current_row == len(rows) - 1: # We are iterating through the last row so simply yield the number as it has no children
            yield [num]
        else:
            for child in routes(rows,current_row+1,i): #This is not the last row so get all children of this number and yield them
                yield [num] + child


numOfTries = input("Please enter the number of tries:")
Tries = int(numOfTries)
for count in range(Tries):
    numstr= input("Please enter the height:")
    rows = int(numstr)
    triangle(rows)
    routes(triangle)
    max(routes(triangle),key=sum)
```

The error i get after inputting all my values for triangle:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/sa1.py", line 25, in <module>
    max(routes(triangle),key=sum)
  File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/sa1.py", line 10, in routes
    for i,num in enumerate(rows[current_row]): #gets the index and number of each number in the row
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Where is my error in my code? Need some help.. Thanks...

Comment: What is `routes(triangle)` supposed to mean?

Comment: triangle(rows) does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying ot get the value of `PrintingList`, created inside the `triangle` function as the `rows`variable inside the `routes` function.

For your program to work that way you have to add a return statement in your triangle function - that is, add a `return PrintingList` as the last statement there - and store this value when you call the function, and pass the stored value to the `routes` function - which means, the ending of your program should read something like:

```
result = triangle(rows)
routes(result)
max(routes(triangle),key=sum)
```

That will fix *this* problem, there may be other issues in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

You are using:

```
routes(triangle)
```

The `triangle` name refers to a function, which is passed as the first argument `rows` to function `routes`. In the function body, `rows[current_row]` yields the error as `rows` is indeed a function.

I don't really see what you are trying to do. Perhaps you want to return `PrintingList` from `triangles` and pass this result in turn to function `routes` ?

Answer (score -3):

As the traceback stated, its in like 25 and line 10. It's saying that the function is not subscriptable, which is true, you can't subscribe to a function. You can subscribe to, however:

```
String:  "x"[2] == "foo"
Tuple:   (2,5,2,7)[3] == 7
List:    [1,2,3,"foo"][3] == "foo"
Dict:    {"a":1, "b":5, "c":5}["a"] == 1
```